# convert %DATE% FROM yyyy-mm to yyyy-<monthname>

Tags: date, windows-7

I currently extract `yyy-mm` from `%DATE%` string using the following statement:

```
C:\> echo %DATE:~5,2%
     08                  (prints month code)
```

but I'd like to print the proper name of the month, like so:

```
C:\> echo ????
     August
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the role of regex here?

Comment: whoops. Originally started writing this thinking I'd have to use regex. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following powershell command
    `Get-Help Get-Date -Full` I found the following command to give you exactly what you want.  It was listed in the NOTES section.

Using this:
  `Get-Date -UFormat %B`

Returns this:
  `August`

Just remember to do all of this in powershell.  I hope this helps!